# Handle multiple forms with React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

In my React app, I have a 3-step sign-up process, and to handle forms, I am using React Hook Form. The Auth component renders a specific form depending on the route.

The Auth Component:

```
import { AppRoute } from "@/enums/enums.js";
import { useAppDispatch, useCallback, useLocation } from "@/hooks/hooks.js";
import { type UserSignUpBasicRequestDto } from "#/users/users.js";
import { actions as authActions } from "~/slices/auth/auth.js";

import {
  AuthLayout,
  SignInForm,
  SignUpAdditionalInfoForm,
  SignUpBasicForm,
  SignUpInterestsForm
} from "./libs/components/components.js";

const Auth: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const handleSignInSubmit = useCallback((): void => {}, []);

  const handleSignUpSubmit = useCallback((): void => {}, []);

  const getLayout = (path: string): React.ReactNode => {
    switch (path) {
      case AppRoute.SIGN_IN: {
        return <SignInForm onSubmit={handleSignInSubmit} />;
      }
      case AppRoute.SIGN_UP: {
        return <SignUpBasicForm onSubmit={handleSignUpSubmit} />;
      }
      case AppRoute.SIGN_UP_ADDITIONAL_INFO: {
        return <SignUpAdditionalInfoForm onSubmit={handleSignUpSubmit} />;
      }
      case AppRoute.SIGN_UP_INTERESTS: {
        return <SignUpInterestsForm onSubmit={handleSignUpSubmit} />;
      }
    }

    return null;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AuthLayout>{getLayout(pathname)}</AuthLayout>
    </>
  );
};

export { Auth };
```

I believe the best way to handle this process is to save all data from each step in one state and send them to the server. I've came up with several solutions:

1. Use a single useForm hook in the Auth component with all the data neded for the three forms. However, in this case I need to pass additional fields like controll and errors to all those forms, which might make it less flexible.
2. Call the useForm hook separately in all the form components and save the data in the localStorage. After form submission and processing the data, delete the data from localStorage.
3. I also thought about save the data in the url hash, but I think it isn't the best idea.

Which option is the best, and are there any better options for handling this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest 2 with updates.

Call the useForm hook separately in all the form **components and sync all forms with a context.** In this way you can interact between forms, like **validation and updates**.

After each form submission process the data and update context, store in local storage if needed.

The same can be implemented without context. **Context would help to reduce the complexity a little bit**.